# EF 5.0 Multiplicity Error On Simple Mapping

Tags: entity-framework, code-first

I have the following domain objects:

```
public class Person 
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public int? FatherId {get; set;}
    public int? MotherId {get; set;}
    public int? HomeChurchId {get; set;}
    public int? BirthCountryId {get; set;}

    public Parent Father {get; set;}
    public Parent Mother {get; set;}
    public Church HomeChurch {get; set;}
    public Country BirthCountry {get; set;}
}

public class Parent
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class Church
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}

public class Country
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    ...
}
```

When mapping Person, all of these properties are mapped pretty much the same way:

```
HasOptional(p => p.Father).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.FatherId);
HasOptional(p => p.BirthCountry).WithMany().HasForeignKey(p => p.BirthCountryId);    
...
```

The problem is, with BirthCountry I receive the following error when I try to query Person:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

System.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmAssociationType: : Multiplicity conflicts with the
referential constraint in Role 'Person_BirthCountry_Target' in relationship
'Person_BirthCountry'. Because all of the properties in the Dependent Role are 
non-nullable, multiplicity of the Principal Role must be '1'.
```

If I remove the BirthCountry property (and mapping) everything works fine.  What is confusing to me is that BirthCountry is set up just like every other nullable property in Person.  Why aren't the other properties giving me the same error?

Thanks for whatever help you can offer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Ignorance is not bliss ... its just plain frustrating.

I finally realized that I had a [Required] attribute on BirthCountryId.  This was causing the problem ... which totally makes sense.  I can't tell EF that its optional and required at the same time.

Hope this saves someone else from the same frustration I went through.

Comment: I'm still searching way to add [Required] attribute to ForeignKeyField. Did you have an answer for fixing this error?

Comment: Actually, my error was **because** of the `[Required]` attribute.  Removing the attribute fixed my problem.  The issue is, you can't declare it as a nullable int (implying that it is nullable and therefore not required) and add an attribute telling EF that it is required.  If it's required, then you shouldn't be declaring it a nullable int.

Comment: I know that remove [Required] attribute then everything works fine. But actually, string is nullable, they can be not null able in EF with [Required] attribute. And we can get ErrorMessage when they is null or empty

Comment: My situation was a bit different in that I was dealing with int values not string.  How is that field defined in your table?  Do you allow nulls in the database?  If not, it could be that your error stems from that.  IOW, if you're database is configured to not accept null values and you pass it a null value, then you're going to get an error.

Comment: Nice. I had two `.WithOptional()`s in my `DbContext` that needed to be `.WithRequired()`s. Close enough for a +1. ;^) Curse you, ORMs! Stop "making my life easier"! ;^D